# Eigenvector convergence

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $\{A_k\}, A$ are $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ matrices such that $A_k \rightarrow A$. How do I show that the dominant eigenvectors of $A_k$ converge to the dominant eigenvector of $A$. By dominant eigenvector, I mean eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue with the maximum absolute value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $A_k x_k = \lambda_k x_k$, with $\|x_k\|=1$, $\lambda_k$ being one dominant eigenvalue of $A_k$, which means that 
$A_k - \tau I$ is invertible for all $\tau$ with $|\tau|>|\lambda_k|$.

Then by extracting a subsequence, $x_{k'}\to x$ with $\|x\|=1$. This implies
that 
$$
\lambda_{k'} x_{k'} = A_{k'} x_{k'} \to Ax.
$$
Since $(x_k)$ is bounded, it follows that $(\lambda_k)$ is bounded as well. Thus, we can extract another subsequence such that $\lambda_{k''}\to \lambda$. Then it follows
$$
Ax = \lambda x,
$$
and since $\|x\|=1$, this implies that $(x,\lambda)$ is an eigenpair.

It remains to prove that $\lambda$ is the dominant eigenvalue of $A$, i.e. $|\lambda|>|\lambda'|$ for all other eigenvalues of $A$. Let me show this under the assumption that all the matrices $A_k$ is symmetric (or complex normal $AA^H=A^HA$). I do not know how to prove this in the general case.

For such matrices, it holds $|\lambda_k|=\|A_k\|_2$, where $\|\cdot\|_2$ is the matrix 2-norm. 
Since norms on finite-dimensional spaces are equivalent it follows $\|A_k\|_2\to \|A\|_2$.
Passing to the limit on the subsequence, yields $|\lambda|=\|A\|_2$.
Since $A$ is symmetric (or normal), $|\lambda|$ is the dominant eigenvalue.

Hence, we proved that any subsequence of $(x_k,\lambda_k)$ contains a subsequence converging to a $(x,\lambda)$, where $\lambda$ is *the* dominant eigenvalue of $A$ and $x$ is *some* eigenvector to $\lambda$.

It follows that the sequence $(\lambda_k)$ converges to $\lambda$. Convergence of eigenvector cannot be expected without some further normalization ($x_k$ and $-x_k$ both satisfy the assumptions, so we can multiply some of the vectors $x_k$ by $-1$ without violating the assumptions).

Comment: Where are you using $A - \tau$ is invertible for $\tau>|\lambda|$?

Comment: Nowhere, it seems. I tried to use this property to prove the claim for the non-symmetric case. But was not successfull.